# 'Class not found' when running JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, playframework, classnotfoundexception

I've got a project setup in IntelliJ 13.1.4 which always worked fine (including tests), but suddenly I can't run tests anymore. No project settings have been changed since last tests ran, no additional tests have been added, all references in the tests work, the rest of the project runs fine and all tests compile successfully. I am kind of dry on ideas what the issue might be.

```
Class not found: "models.utils.ArrangementModelTest"
```

*EDIT*

I tried a checkout of an older version of which I am sure the tests worked (since I just committed a new test). But that version also doesn't work anymore :S

Comment: Time ago I had exactly the same problem and it was due to by mistake I had excluded the test class from compilation (although I cannot view excluded on project browser). Could you check if class ArrangementModelTest is on Settings > Compiler > Excludes? Maybe can be the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the issue was fixed by a couple of steps:

1. Exit Intellij
2. Delete .IntelliJIdea13 and .IdealC13
3. I am using typesafe activator, run activator clean on project level
4. Delete intellij related files in project
5. Run activator idea on project level
6. Start IntelliJ
7. Re-install plugins, setup project, enz.

The culprit seemed to be the Play 2.0 plugin for IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the project and in eclipse i know, "clean project" it should help.

Comment: Try checking project build path, maybe by accident some of resources are excluded. If its ok try restarting IntelliJ ;-)

Comment: Build path is fine, all stuff that should be there is there. Re-install of IntelliJ and building the project files, build path, etc also didn't work.

Comment: The problem seems to be more likely with compilation. Your application is not compiled successfully. Try checking the build path, clean and build the project, if you are using maven, try maven clean and then install.